# Edittext с выпадающим списком и автоподстановкой по первым символам

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы вводя текст в поле, по первым символам была подстановка контактов из моей базы данных. (что-то между edittext и spinner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)